# Solve the differential equation $2y'' + (y')^2 = -1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the differential equation $2y'' + (y')^2 = -1$ Any ideas on this? Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: Idea (possibly a bad one): Try the substitution $u=y'$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y' = x$.

This transforms the problem into:

$2x' + x^2 = -1$

This yields:

$x(t) = \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}(c-t)\right)$

Substituting back yields:

$$\displaystyle y' = \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}(c-t)\right)$$

Can you take it from there?

Hint:

You should arrive at:

$$\displaystyle y(t) = 2 \log\left(\cos\left(\frac{c-t}{2}\right)\right)+ k_1$$

Comment: @amWhy: Believe it or not, I feel about 10% of my old self in all areas of math and have to get back up to speed! Thanks for the nice comments!

Comment: Believe me, Amzoti! I know what you mean ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I get my fix by doing reviews, which always makes me feel like I am helping the MSE Community! Always moving forward!